# Работа с reduce

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать как работает `reduce`, но столкнулся с одной проблемой и не могу понять как её решить. Хочу написать функцию, которая принимает объект, как аргумент и возвращает новый массив с именами ключей - значение, которых false.
Например:

```
Input : { isActive: false, isPilot: true };

Output : ['isActive']
```

Написал вот такой вот код:

```
function test(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
   .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => { 
     if (value === false)  acc = [key]
  return acc;
}, []);
}
```

Но моя функция, показывает только последний ключ с `false`, подскажите правильное направление для решения.

Answer (score 1):

`acc` - это массив. Для добавления элемента в массив можно использовать метод [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```js
var o = {
  isActive: false,
  isPilot: true
};

function test(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      if (value === false) acc.push(key);
      return acc;
    }, []);
}

console.log(test(o));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, совсем забыл за .push

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
  isActive: false,
  isPilot: true
};


function test(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      if (value === false) acc.push(key);
      return acc;
    }, []);
}

console.log(test(obj));
```